# Add more than 3 y-axis in Highcharts. 4th y-axis values aren't displayed

Tags: javascript, json, api, highcharts, yaxis

I've tried to figure out how to add multiple y-axis were the right hand side of the chart could be x amount of measurments to be displayed. The issue is only 3 out of 4 y-axis values are displayed.

What I want to be displayed https://gyazo.com/623c1c120c3794cf404c82f7aa36119e

Example from Highcharts docs https://jsfiddle.net/ojzc2h51/

My dummy code here https://jsfiddle.net/Lamborobin/ojzc2h51/1/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Average Monthly Weather Data for Tokyo'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: [{
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        crosshair: true
    }],
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: {
            format: '{value}°C',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
            }
        },
        opposite: true

    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} mm',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        }

    }, { // Tertiary yAxis
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} mb',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        opposite: true
    }, { // Tertiary yAxis
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Test',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value}',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3]
            }
        },
        opposite: true
    }],
    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        x: 80,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 55,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || 'rgba(255,255,255,0.25)'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Rainfall',
        type: 'column',
        yAxis: 1,
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' mm'
        }

    }, {
        name: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
        type: 'spline',
        yAxis: 2,
        data: [1016, 1016, 1015.9, 1015.5, 1012.3, 1009.5, 1009.6, 1010.2, 1013.1, 1016.9, 1018.2, 1016.7],
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        dashStyle: 'shortdot',
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' mb'
        }

    }, {
        name: 'Temperature',
        type: 'spline',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' °C'
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Test',
        type: 'spline',
        data: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]

    }]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the new series to the `yAxis`:

```
series: [..., {
    name: 'Test',
    type: 'spline',
    data: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
    yAxis: 3
}]
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2fqa8rcs/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.spline.yAxis